# Directing NJsonSchema to treat custom dictionary like regular Dictionary<string, Something>

Tags: c#, njsonschema

Let's say I have these configuration classes:

```
public class Config
{
    [Required]
    public ConfigDictionary<string> Files { get; set; }
}

public class ConfigDictionary<T> : Dictionary<string, T>
{
    public ConfigDictionary() : base(StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) { }
}
```

And I do something like this:

```
var json = File.ReadAllText(config);
var schema = JsonSchema4.FromType<Config>();
var validationResults = schema.Validate(json);
```

NJsonSchema handles `Dictionary<string, string>` the way I would expect, but the Files property as `ConfigDictionary<string>` is not treated like a dictionary in the way I would expect.

Is there anyway I can get NJsonSchema to treat `ConfigDictionary<T>` like `Dictionary<string, T>`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write a type mapper and use FromType inside it: https://github.com/NJsonSchema/NJsonSchema/wiki/Type-Mappers

Otherwise create an issue on the project and we can discuss this scenario.